Android: SSLHandshakeException when connecting to my https server
The https connection to my API hosted on my gandi.net https server SUDDENLY no longer works (the problem probably started on April 1st 2024). This problem only occurs when the connection is made from an Android device (several Android devices tested); no problem when connecting from iOS.
Here is the error that is obtained on the client side (i.e. in the Android app) when a connection attempt is made:
NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed

java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Response is unreliable: its validity interval is out-of-date

Everything worked properly before. The problem appeared suddenly on ALL MY APPS in production.
I tested several Android devices, in wifi and 4G, two have identical DNS in the phone settings, the others have different DNS. I also tested the API by launching my Android app in an Android simulator on my Mac OS computer, same problem.
As already said, the API works without problems on iOS.
When I open the API root link in a browser, whether in a browser on my Mac or on my various Android devices, the API responds correctly.
The problem therefore only occurs when the API is called from the Java code of my Android app. The problem appeared suddenly without me being able to explain it.
I suspected a problem with the time change this weekend (1 hour change). But my devices are on time (correct time and date set automatically), I restarted my devices, cleared the app cache, the problem was not resolved.
I restarted my https instance; the problem has not been resolved.
Any idea how to solve this issue ? What should I set in my network_security_config.xml ?
Thanks for your help.

Each SSL certificate has a start and an end date. If you are outside of that validity period the certification is invalid - thus useless and you get the error you have posted. A common error is a wrong local time so check the devices you use if the local date is correct.

@toto_tata were you able to find root cause of this problem?

@ParthGupta My app didn't work during 48 hours and everything came back after that... I think that there is something mysterious on Google side with DNS or something like that. What is your conclusion ?

@toto_tata thanks for reply. We are still facing this issue. We have should shown dialog to user in this case. We are still not able to find RCA of this issue. Let me know if you find anything
